# training svm in matlab with multiple data set

Tags: matlab

I have multiple data set which is x y data and each data set represent same class, also i have multiple data set for other 2 classes.

Do I need to train on merged x y data or do i need to call training function for each data set, note that each data set is same class? And there are multiple data set for each class type.

I have like 150 x y data set for class 1, and I have like 68 for class 2 and like 55 for class 3. How do i train support vector machince (SVM) in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your project, you want to train a classifier on a dataset containing 3 distinct classes.

Generally, you want to tag your data with the classes you want your network to learn, so it can check in training how much it still deviates from the solution after "guessing" so it can optimize its weights for the next iteration.

You also want to split your data set into a training set, which will be used for learning, and 2 portions with different data, the network doesn't "know" yet and will provide a good reference.
These two are a validation set, which is used for additional validation during training and a testing set, which is used for testing the accuracy after training.

One could proceed like this:

1. accumulate the training data in a 4D Matrix `A`, where the first 2 dimension would be your values for `x` and `y` and the third dimension would be the index of the XY matrix. You can do that using `A = horzconcat(x,y)`
2. use the 4th dimension to tag your data according to your class. In your case, write 1 in the first 150 elements, 2 in the following 68 and 3 in the last 55
3. shuffle your tagged dataset. You can use `randperm` to create a random index and then iterate through the set
4. split your dataset in a training, validation and testing portion. (usually 60%, 20%, 20% are reasonable)
5. split those sets each into a 3D X matrix containing your training data and a Y vector containing the solution to each training data.
6. In your training options, specify your validation data with your validation portion, for example:

   ```
   training_options =  trainingOptions ...
                       ('sgdm', ...
                       'Verbose', 1 ,...
                       'VerboseFrequency' , 20, ...
                       'MaxEpochs', 30, ...
                       'MiniBatchSize', 128, ...
                       'Shuffle', 'every-epoch', ...
                       **'ValidationData', {X_validate, categorical(Y_validate)},...**
                       'ValidationFrequency', 20, ...
                       'ValidationPatience', 5, ...
                       'InitialLearnRate', 0.001, ...
                       'L2Regularization', 0, ...
                       'Momentum', 0, ...
                       'ExecutionEnvironment', 'cpu', ...
                       'Plots','training-progress');
   ```
7. train your neural network Matlab object with

   ```
   [nn, nn_info] = trainNetwork(X_train, categorical(Y_train), ...
                 layers, training_options);
   ```
8. Retrieve the accuracy of the trained network:

   ```
   acurracy = sum(Y_test_predictions == categorical(Y_test) )/ ...
          size(Y_test, 1)
   ```

I applied this method for a convolutional network, which worked just fine.
Hope this helps,

all the best,
Simon

Comment: Thanks i am little confused i actually have 150 text files with xy data which denotes class 1, also have 68 text files with xy data which denotes class 2,and lastly have 55 text files with xy data which denotes class 3. Do i need to do something like merge the data or not?

Comment: Merging the data is only done so you don‘t loose the relationship from your X and Y files when shuffling. Did you tag your datat sets already or is it just raw data? If the second is true please follow the guide I posted

Comment: In any case you‘d have to merge your data, so you have all three classes represented in your training, validation and test sets.

Comment: A = horzconcat(x,y) is there a reason why u need to do this for your solution?

Comment: I used horzcat to make one big matrix from your three classes. This enables you to shuffle your whole training set after tagging it, preserving the corresponding tag for each matrix and providing training data for each class when creating training, validation and test set

Comment: Thanks sir i am trying to run this what do i need to give for layers my data is x y scatter data and label associated with each point?